# Creating box and whisker plot for each excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am VERY new to the world of python/pandas/matplotlib, but I have been using it recently to create box and whisker plots. I was curious how to create a box and whisker plot for each sheet using a specific column of data, i.e. I have 17 sheets, and I need column called HMB and DV from each. I think want to plot 17 data sets on a Box and Whisker for HMB and another 17 data sets on the DV plot. Below is what I have so far.

I can open the file, and get all the sheets into list_dfs, but then don't know where to go from there. I was going to try and manually slice each set (as I started below before coming here for help), but when I have more data in the future, I don't want to have to do that by hand. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlrd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

excel_file =  'Comparison.xlsm'

list_dfs = []

xls = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file,on_demand=True)
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names():
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name)
    list_dfs.append(df) 
#print(len(list_dfs))

a = list_dfs[0]
b = list_dfs[1]
c = list_dfs[2]
d = list_dfs[3]
e = list_dfs[4]
f = list_dfs[5]

data_a = a.loc[:,['DV','HMB']]
data_b = b.loc[:,['DV','HMB']]
```

I tried to include a picture of what each sheet looks like. They all have the same header and layout which is helpful.

**edit**

So I added the code that was suggested below and removed the manual slicing, and now I have all of my data in a dictionary format, but I can't get pandas or matplotlib to plot for me. I wonder if there is a step that I am missing. I was thinking of making one dictionary for HMB and one for DV. I would like to have one box and whisker plot on the same subplot for each entry in the list.

```
d_dv = {}
d_hmb = {}
for i, sheet_name in enumerate(xls.sheet_names()):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name)
    d_dv["PSPPM" + str(i)] = df.loc[:,['DV']]
    d_hmb["HMB" + str(i)] = df.loc[:,['HMB']]
```

[image: Example of each sheets format]

Answer (score 1):

You can start by creating each sliced df within the same loop. To do so you can define a dictionary and add a new entry on each iteration:

```
d = {}
for i, sheet_name in enumerate(xls.sheet_names()):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name)
    d["data" + str(i)] = df.loc[:,['DV','HMB']]
```